# Jquery customized tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to give a option to the users in my web application to create as many tabs as they can.
When they click on the "add button" I should be able to add new blank tab where they are drag the widgets. I am not getting how to do it using jquery.

Can any one suggest me the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery-UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation) provides a method to add tabs dynamically.